# Netbeans 7.2 won't start on Windows 7 java.io.FileNotFoundException: \lock (Access is denied)

Tags: windows-7, netbeans

ever since I installed Netbeans 7.2 on my Windows 7 32bit machine I can't get it to work.
If I do a trace to netbeans.log I get a file accesss error for c:\lock

Even when I right-click and select Run as Administrator I'm unable to start Netbeans 7.2

I do not get this error when uninstalling and installing netbeans 7.1

Comment: Where is it installing netbeans? are you running the installer as Admin?

Comment: It's installing in c:\program files\netbeans\

I've had indeed installed Netbeans 7.2 as an Administrator. I even tried logging in as administrator and trying to start Netbeans.

I've also tried to install it on another hdd (h:\) which I also have full control over.

Answer (score 0):

Try Compatibility mode as XP SP2. It works for me, I used "Troubleshoot Compatibility" (of right click menu of NetBeans App icon) and then "Try recommended settings" .. finally, "Start the program...".

I think this incompatibility may be occur due to my JDK version that is not v7.ux (is 6.u25).

*Update:* I am using jdk7u9 and Netbeans 7.2 now, but NetBeans can not start normally yet!

Comment: Please register your account here, and don't use the option to post without logging in. This way you won't lose your account and you can always edit your posts freely.

Comment: If this site be useful for me and i need to return here more, i will register my account in future surely :)
(I will keep my cookies safe)
Thank you anyway...